# Custom styles for Wordpress TinyMCE

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, wordpress-theming

I've read several tutorials for adding custom styles to the WYSIWYG (TinyMCE) editor. None of them seem to work in the newest version(s) of Wordpress. I'm using v3.3.2. The [instructions from the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Buttons) work, but in a limited way...

NOTE: To be 100% clear, I'm trying to add a "Styles" dropdown which the author can use to apply my custom styles to the text. (Please don't confuse my question with how to style the editor its self, using editor-style.css... )

I managed to get the code working, but only using the commented-out line in `my_mce_before_init()`. The problem with this version is that it adds the class with a generic `<span>`. I'm trying to use the more powerful version of the code (as shown below), but something isn't quite right. The styles drop-down box appears, but it's blank. If I click it the first item is says "Styles" but does nothing. I suspect there's something off about my array. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable than me can set me straight.

Here's the relevant code in my theme's functions.php...

Here's how I add the button:

```
// Add the Style selectbox to the second row of MCE buttons
function my_mce_buttons_2($buttons)
{
    array_unshift($buttons, 'styleselect');
    return $buttons;
}
add_filter('mce_buttons_2', 'my_mce_buttons_2');
```

Here's how I add the styles (it works when I uncomment the ):

```
//Define the actual styles that will be in the box
function my_mce_before_init($init_array)
{
    // add classes using a ; separated values
    //$init_array['theme_advanced_styles'] = "Section Head=section-head;Sub Section Head=sub-section-head";

    $temp_array['theme_advanced_styles'] = array(
        array(
            'title' => 'Section Head',
            'block' => 'h3',
            'classes' => 'section-head'
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Sub Section Head',
            'block' => 'h4',
            'classes' => 'sub-section-head'
        )       
    );

    $styles_array = json_encode( $temp_array['theme_advanced_styles'] );

            //  THIS IS THE PROBLEM !!!! READ BELOW
    $init_array['theme_advanced_styles'] = $styles_array;

    return $init_array;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_mce_before_init');
```

**UPDATE: I figured it out (see my answer below). Before you scroll down, notice in the code above, `theme_advanced_styles` is the wrong key. It should be `style_formats` when defining the custom styles in the way that I'm doing. I suspect this is a common mistake.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## AHA!

I found the problem: the two different versions of defining the custom classes must be added to different keys in the settings array.

This version...

```
"Section Head=section-head;Sub Section Head=sub-section-head";
```

...needs to be the value of `'theme_advanced_styles'`.

Whereas this version...

```
$style_formats = array(
array(
    'title' => 'Column',
    'block' => 'div',
    'classes' => 'col',
    'wrapper' => true
    ),
);
```

...needs to be the value of `'style_formats'` in the TinyMCE settings array.

I had changed to the second style but hadn't noticed the different key for the array.

Comment: Could you please provide the fully working code? I'm trying to get this to work too, but haven't had any luck yet.

Comment: Use my original code from the question, but replace 'theme_advanced_styles' with 'style_formats'.

Comment: FYI... To those trying to get this to work - it does - the trick not mentioned in the answer (but which is in the question) is that you *must* `json_encode` that `$style_formats` array before assigning it to the `style_formats` setting

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're using this (awesome) tutorial: http://alisothegeek.com/2011/05/tinymce-styles-dropdown-wordpress-visual-editor/
Worked great for me so I compared your code with mine: it seems you lack a

```
'wrapper' => true
```

as a fourth parameter to each sub-array. This is needed for adding a class on a parent element of your selection  (it can broaden your selection) and not creating a new element around your exact selection before adding it a class.
Thus if you select part of a paragraph or part of 2 paragraphs, it'll select the whole paragraph(s) (not so sure about the 2 paragraphs thing, please test :) but at least it won't create inline element around your exact selection).

From the documentation (above link):

```
wrapper [optional, default = false]
  if set to true, creates a new block-level element
  around any selected block-level elements
```

My customization:

```
$style_formats = array(
    array(
        'title' => 'Column',
        'block' => 'div',
        'classes' => 'col',
        'wrapper' => true
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Some div with a class',
        'block' => 'div',
        'classes' => 'some_class',
        'wrapper' => true
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Title with other CSS',
        'selector' => 'h3',
        'classes' => 'other_style'
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Read more link',
        'selector' => 'a',
        'classes' => 'more'
    )
);
```

Hope it works for you

Comment: Thanks Felipe. That is one of the first tutorials that I found, but it doesn't work for me as is. I tried both adding his code, and installing his plugin, and in both cases I get a white screen of death when it's active/un-commented. If you look at the comments below, it appears I'm not the only one. What version of Wordpress are you running?

Comment: I jus double-checked it and it still doesn't work, even with the `'wrapper'=>true`. To be safe, I reverted to the (commented) version which defines the options as a string and it still does work... (but  by adding `<span>`s around everything). So it means there MUST be something wrong with the way I'm declaring the classes in my array. The frustrating thing is that I can't find any documentation on that alternative. The TinyMCE documentation (http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:theme_advanced_styles) is almost non-existant and doesn't mention this alternative at all.

Comment: ...I just noticed that there was another difference that we'd over-looked (see my answer). Thanks so much for your help anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Wordpress provides a function for adding a custom stylesheet to the editor: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_editor_style